# How to crisp breaded foods the next day (especially panko)

Tags: frying, fish, breadcrumbs, breading

I breaded some fish today, and the other day, chicken. Unfortunately, I over-estimated, and fried a whole bunch that we didn't eat. If I nuke it (microwave it) the next day, it comes out soggy and limp.

Bummer.

How can I actually reheat this and regain some of the panko crisp? Baking seems to be the right answer, except that panko breading burns really, really fast (mine is already a dark-brown from cooking it on medium).

Comment: See related:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29393/re-fry-fried-food

Comment: The breadcrumbs tag already existed - I don't think we need an extra tag for panko.

Comment: @Jefromi I think a synonym would be good, because it's non-obvious. I'll bring it up on meta.

Comment: @ashes999 Don't bother, I'll create it. (I think it'll be obvious to most people, though: panko is a type of breadcrumbs. Breadcrumbs on wikipedia is the first hit if you search for panko.)

Comment: @Jefromi we can discuss it here (I already created it when I saw your comment. I mean the cooking technique (breading/battering), not panko. http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1851/meta-tags-for-panko-and-breading

Answer (score 4):

Reheating fried food is extremely challenging.

The least bad method is probably baking in a slow oven, about 250-300 F.  You want to reheat only enough to get the food warm enough to enjoy, but not so piping hot that it would trigger additional browning.

At these low temperatures, you should not get too much additional browning, although you will never have the ideal crispy texture that first-fried foods have.

Comment: ...and don't do it straight out of the refrigerator. Allow the food to come to room temperature before putting in a low oven.

Comment: A toaster oven seems to work reasonably well for this.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a hotter temperature 400 to 425 degrees minimum.  If the food has already been cooked, you do not need to have the internal temperatures reach 165.
Higher oven temperatures will drive off moisture from the coating enhancing the crispiness.  They will most likely never be as crispy as fried but this will be better than slow, low heat.
Try it versus the low heat.