# Could I store breaded chicken breasts in the fridge?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I'm practicing Chicken Schnitzel, and it seems the most time it takes for me is breading the chicken. Right now, I am storing it fried, but it seems so, the quality is gone when I reheat it in the microwave. Would it be a good idea to keep the breaded Schnitzel pieces (with flour, egg and panko) in the fridge?

I've seen [this thread](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40035/how-to-crisp-breaded-foods-the-next-day-especially-panko) but I unfortunately don't have an oven

Comment: How much are you making at once?  For best quality you want to bread just before frying.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting your temperature right? Oil should be at 175 C for deep frying, and you should be using a lot of oil. This will usually take longer to take up to temperature than breading the schnitzel (although there is of course a lot of variability depending on how conveniently yous store the different ingredients, how agile you are, etc.)

Comment: Would you be open to purchasing an Air Fryer? They're magical.